# Filling Armadillo sparse matrix in parallel with OpenMP

Tags: c++, performance, openmp, rcpp, armadillo

I need to represent a very large block-bidiagonal matrix as a sparse matrix in Armadillo. I have all the values of all the blocks into two `arma::field<arma::mat>` lists, so I only need to cast them into a `arma::sp_mat` object.

I can do it:

- sequentially (slower)
- in parallel by using `arma::mat` and then converting the dense matrix into a sparse matrix (faster)

I would like to fill the `arma::sp_mat` directly in parallel, which should be the fastest route. I tried with code similar to the snippet below (using Rcpp), but it crashes and I'm guessing it's because of the way sparse matrices are grown in Armadillo. Is there a way to make it work?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <omp.h>

arma::sp_mat test_ll(int blocks=10, int rowcol_per_block=250){
  arma::mat mat1 = arma::randn() * arma::ones(rowcol_per_block, rowcol_per_block);

  arma::sp_mat tester(blocks * rowcol_per_block, 
                      blocks * rowcol_per_block);

#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0; i<blocks; i++){
    tester.submat( i*rowcol_per_block, i*rowcol_per_block, 
                   (i+1)*rowcol_per_block-1, (i+1)*rowcol_per_block-1) = mat1;

  }
  return tester;
}
```

I tried pre-filling all the blocks of a appropriately-sized `sp_mat` and then *changing* them in parallel, but that also crashes.

**Update** 
No difference in using the [#2 constructor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) to initialize the `sp_mat` (providing non-zero locations and filling them with 1, and then changing them in parallel). That also fails.

Comment: Have a look at the Armadillo constructors.  We use the ones with memory re-use, which is generally the right plan ("no copies") but could hurt you here.  Try with memory distinct from R, then return at end (maybe explicitly copying).

Comment: Right now I only use R as high level interface so everything happens in Armadillo. I'm trying with 'form 2' of the `sp_mat` constructor now to see whether that will play nicely with omp

Comment: One approach I also like is to try my code outside of R in an independent `main()`.  If and when that works, glue it to R for data i/o and all the other niceties.

Comment: Which code? As an update, constructor #2 also fails